# How do I resolve the navigation drawer going below the status bar for Lollipop+ but not for Pre-Lollipop?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Does Lollipop have something similar to `?attr/actionBarSize` that I could use?

Pre-Lollipop Version:

[image]

Lollipop+ Version:

[image]

`fitSystemWindows=true` also adds a different problem:

[image]